# error while installing mysqlclient in django project in pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Got this problem while installing mysqlclient in pycharm settings

ERROR: Command "'C:\Users\miaw\PycharmProjects\PleaseWork\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='"'"'C:\Users\miaw\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\mysqlclient\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\miaw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qeq94583\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\miaw\PycharmProjects\PleaseWork\venv\include\site\python3.6\mysqlclient'" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\miaw\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\mysqlclient\

Comment: Show us the command you used to install.

Comment: What had did you read about it? what have you tried in order to fix it?

Comment: pip install mysqlclient @JohnGordon and in pycharm settings u can add it

Comment: @RaydelMiranda i'm trying to fix the problem

Comment: @taniiit, Ok I just ask because is good for people that have the intention to help, to know what have you tried in order to not duplicate effort.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda i'm so sorry i didn't understand you well !! so i'm trying to connect my database whish is sql to my django project and for that i must install mysqlclient with pip install mysqlclient and the result that i had this problem thank you and sorry again :)

Answer (score 0):

hey guys i just fixed the problem by installing the package of "sqlclient" in this link https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient and for more informations please check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SnE0r7g2lE